# how to setup docker in local machine after setup sxa headless application

Tags: docker, nextjs, sxa-jss

I have `Sitecore SXA Headless` with a `Next.js` application running on my local machine. Now, I want to set up Docker for this application. Could you please provide steps for this?

Sitecore version: `Sitecore XP 10.3`. I have a couple of queries:

1. If we install Docker in the existing application (SXA Headless with Next.js), will it affect any existing functionality?
2. Is it advisable to set up Docker in the existing headless application, or should we create a new application?

kindly provide your ideas for this. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. It should not affect any of functionality. Docker is used just for containerization that helps you to recreate similar setup as close to upper environments. There is no change in features provided. Also containerized setup can be used for local development keeping your other environments unaffected.
2. Sitecore already provides [templates for headless SXA implementation with Docker](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/19/sitecore-headless-development/walkthrough--setting-up-a-development-environment-with-the-sitecore-containers-template-for-next-js.html). I would suggest to set it up and add your code in it to make this work. Docker boosts development but using it, is not a real development. As a Sitecore developer, you can easily debug non-working code compared to debugging  non-working Docker/containers (I was recently involved in research work related to Docker so this is a voice within..)

Hope this helps !

Unrelated to your question, as you are moving to Docker, here is my recent research work related to [Sitecore Containers without Docker Desktop](https://blogs.perficient.com/2023/10/12/sitecore-containers-without-docker-desktop/) which may benefit you.